# C++ How to create a bitmap file

Tags: c++, bitmap, bmp, ofstream

I am trying to figure out how to create a bitmap file in C++ VS.  Currently I have taken in the file name and adding the ".bmp" extension to create the file.  I want to know how I could change the pixels of the file by making it into different colors or patterns (ie. like a checkerboard)  This is my function that I have and I believe that I have to send 3 different Bytes at a time in order to establish the color of the pixel.

```
void makeCheckerboardBMP(string fileName, int squaresize, int n) {
    ofstream ofs;
    ofs.open(fileName + ".bmp");
    writeHeader(ofs, n, n);

    for(int row = 0; row < n; row++) {
        for(int col = 0; col < n; col++) {

            if(col % 2 == 0) {
                ofs << 0;
                ofs << 0;
                ofs << 0;
            } else {
                ofs << 255;
                ofs << 255;
                ofs << 255;
            }
        }
    }
}

void writeHeader(ostream& out, int width, int height){
    if (width % 4 != 0) {
        cerr << "ERROR: There is a windows-imposed requirement on BMP that the width be a          
multiple of 4.\n";
        cerr << "Your width does not meet this requirement, hence this will fail.  You can fix     
this\n";
        cerr << "by increasing the width to a multiple of 4." << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    BITMAPFILEHEADER tWBFH;
    tWBFH.bfType = 0x4d42;
    tWBFH.bfSize = 14 + 40 + (width*height*3);
    tWBFH.bfReserved1 = 0;
    tWBFH.bfReserved2 = 0;
    tWBFH.bfOffBits = 14 + 40;

    BITMAPINFOHEADER tW2BH;
    memset(&tW2BH,0,40);
    tW2BH.biSize = 40;
    tW2BH.biWidth = width;
    tW2BH.biHeight = height;
    tW2BH.biPlanes = 1;
    tW2BH.biBitCount = 24;
    tW2BH.biCompression = 0;

    out.write((char*)(&tWBFH),14);
    out.write((char*)(&tW2BH),40);
}
```

Comment: (1) Did you close the stream? (2) You can modify the size by modifying the header (it's a property in the header)

Comment: @CommuSoft When an object goes out of scope its destructor is invoked. `ofstream`s destructor calls `close`. So yes, the stream does get closed.

Comment: Yes I did close the stream

Comment: @IInspectable: Well in some programming languages you have to close the stream, and I wouldn't count on such methods. Since you don't know when the destructor will be called, it can take ages. And keeping a file open isn't a good idea since it can cause conflicts with other programs or cause the OS to kill the program when you have too much open files. :D

Comment: @CommuSoft The question is tagged [`c++`](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/c++/info); your reference to *"some programming languages"* is surprising. In the code above you **do** see when the destructor runs. `ofs` is locally scoped; the lifetime is easy to guess. As for the *"too much open files"* argument: Get a real OS.

Comment: I disagree. First of all, if you know 30 languages you start generalizing. It's also part of a healthy coding style not to use that much implicit actions. Second: most OS (W7, Linux,...) will kill a program with too much open files. I think Windows uses a default threshold of `100` and in Linux you can modify it at free will... Of course one can claim that `100` is quite large, but if you run programs on servers for ages, such thresholds can be reached.

Comment: @CommuSoft If you need to generalize you don't know any of the 30 languages well enough. This question is specific to C++. Your question was answered in the code even before you asked. I pointed out that the answer is there. And you still argue that because some other language might interpret the construct differently is reason enough to not trust that C++ does precisely what I described? You're in for a fun future with your compilers.

Comment: Well I'm writing compilers myself (with a focus on garbage collection and thus by extent finalizers) :)... And with all I have seen the past 10 years languages are moving towards convergence... I don't argue C++ cannot be trusted, but everybody can write unreadable code. C++ was design to build efficient code. Todays programming languages like Haskell put more focus on development time. I disagree you don't know any of the languages well enough. Nearly all concepts are recycled everywhere, do you think Mixins just came out of the blue?

Comment: A half year ago, I made a glossary describing general programming language concepts. It can be found here: http://www.scribd.com/doc/122614039/Comparative-Programming-Languages-Glossary

It is based on Programming Language Theory (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_language_theory). Furthermore the ACM devoted a Special Interest Group to program languages called SIGPLAN, therefore I think one can state there is general knowledge about programming languages.

Comment: @CommuSoft Great. This question is tagged C++. C++ implements deterministic garbage collection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given your `writeHeader` is properly implemented this is almost correct. You need to fix 2 issues though:

1. You are writing one `int` per color channel. This should be one byte instead. You need to cast the literals to `unsigned char`.
2. Scanlines in bitmaps need to be `DWORD`-aligned. After your inner loop over `col` you need to write additional bytes to account for this, unless the size in bytes of the row is a multiple of four.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the advice!!!  Changing the int to an unsigned char works.  Now the next problem that I have is actually the size of the checkerboard itself.  It is actually very small compared to the bitmap image that I wanted to actually generate.

Answer (score 6):

These are the two functions I am using for my code (one greyscale, one RGB saving).

Might give you a hint whats going wrong. 
Note: they are done to work, not to be efficient.

```
void SaveBitmapToFile( BYTE* pBitmapBits, LONG lWidth, LONG lHeight,WORD wBitsPerPixel, LPCTSTR lpszFileName )
{
    RGBQUAD palette[256];
    for(int i = 0; i < 256; ++i)
    {
        palette[i].rgbBlue = (byte)i;
        palette[i].rgbGreen = (byte)i;
        palette[i].rgbRed = (byte)i;
    }

    BITMAPINFOHEADER bmpInfoHeader = {0};
    // Set the size
    bmpInfoHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    // Bit count
    bmpInfoHeader.biBitCount = wBitsPerPixel;
    // Use all colors
    bmpInfoHeader.biClrImportant = 0;
    // Use as many colors according to bits per pixel
    bmpInfoHeader.biClrUsed = 0;
    // Store as un Compressed
    bmpInfoHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
    // Set the height in pixels
    bmpInfoHeader.biHeight = lHeight;
    // Width of the Image in pixels
    bmpInfoHeader.biWidth = lWidth;
    // Default number of planes
    bmpInfoHeader.biPlanes = 1;
    // Calculate the image size in bytes
    bmpInfoHeader.biSizeImage = lWidth* lHeight * (wBitsPerPixel/8);

    BITMAPFILEHEADER bfh = {0};
    // This value should be values of BM letters i.e 0x4D42
    // 0x4D = M 0×42 = B storing in reverse order to match with endian

    bfh.bfType = 'B'+('M' << 8);
    // <<8 used to shift ‘M’ to end

    // Offset to the RGBQUAD
    bfh.bfOffBits = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER) + sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + sizeof(RGBQUAD) * 256;
    // Total size of image including size of headers
    bfh.bfSize = bfh.bfOffBits + bmpInfoHeader.biSizeImage;
    // Create the file in disk to write
    HANDLE hFile = CreateFile( lpszFileName,GENERIC_WRITE, 0,NULL,
        CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,NULL);

    if( !hFile ) // return if error opening file
    {
        return;
    }

    DWORD dwWritten = 0;
    // Write the File header
    WriteFile( hFile, &bfh, sizeof(bfh), &dwWritten , NULL );
    // Write the bitmap info header
    WriteFile( hFile, &bmpInfoHeader, sizeof(bmpInfoHeader), &dwWritten, NULL );
    // Write the palette
    WriteFile( hFile, &palette[0], sizeof(RGBQUAD) * 256, &dwWritten, NULL );
    // Write the RGB Data
    if(lWidth%4 == 0)
    {
        WriteFile( hFile, pBitmapBits, bmpInfoHeader.biSizeImage, &dwWritten, NULL );
    }
    else
    {
        char* empty = new char[ 4 - lWidth % 4];
        for(int i = 0; i < lHeight; ++i)
        {
            WriteFile( hFile, &pBitmapBits[i * lWidth], lWidth, &dwWritten, NULL );
            WriteFile( hFile, empty,  4 - lWidth % 4, &dwWritten, NULL );
        }
    }
    // Close the file handle
    CloseHandle( hFile );
}

void SaveBitmapToFileColor( BYTE* pBitmapBits, LONG lWidth, LONG lHeight,WORD wBitsPerPixel, LPCTSTR lpszFileName )
{

    BITMAPINFOHEADER bmpInfoHeader = {0};
    // Set the size
    bmpInfoHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    // Bit count
    bmpInfoHeader.biBitCount = wBitsPerPixel;
    // Use all colors
    bmpInfoHeader.biClrImportant = 0;
    // Use as many colors according to bits per pixel
    bmpInfoHeader.biClrUsed = 0;
    // Store as un Compressed
    bmpInfoHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
    // Set the height in pixels
    bmpInfoHeader.biHeight = lHeight;
    // Width of the Image in pixels
    bmpInfoHeader.biWidth = lWidth;
    // Default number of planes
    bmpInfoHeader.biPlanes = 1;
    // Calculate the image size in bytes
    bmpInfoHeader.biSizeImage = lWidth* lHeight * (wBitsPerPixel/8);

    BITMAPFILEHEADER bfh = {0};
    // This value should be values of BM letters i.e 0x4D42
    // 0x4D = M 0×42 = B storing in reverse order to match with endian

    bfh.bfType = 'B'+('M' << 8);
    // <<8 used to shift ‘M’ to end

    // Offset to the RGBQUAD
    bfh.bfOffBits = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER) + sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER);
    // Total size of image including size of headers
    bfh.bfSize = bfh.bfOffBits + bmpInfoHeader.biSizeImage;
    // Create the file in disk to write
    HANDLE hFile = CreateFile( lpszFileName,GENERIC_WRITE, 0,NULL,
        CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,NULL);

    if( !hFile ) // return if error opening file
    {
        return;
    }

    DWORD dwWritten = 0;
    // Write the File header
    WriteFile( hFile, &bfh, sizeof(bfh), &dwWritten , NULL );
    // Write the bitmap info header
    WriteFile( hFile, &bmpInfoHeader, sizeof(bmpInfoHeader), &dwWritten, NULL );
    // Write the palette
    //WriteFile( hFile, &palette[0], sizeof(RGBQUAD) * 256, &dwWritten, NULL );
    // Write the RGB Data
    if(lWidth%4 == 0)
    {
        WriteFile( hFile, pBitmapBits, bmpInfoHeader.biSizeImage, &dwWritten, NULL );
    }
    else
    {
        char* empty = new char[ 4 - lWidth % 4];
        for(int i = 0; i < lHeight; ++i)
        {
            WriteFile( hFile, &pBitmapBits[i * lWidth], lWidth, &dwWritten, NULL );
            WriteFile( hFile, empty,  4 - lWidth % 4, &dwWritten, NULL );
        }
    }
    // Close the file handle
    CloseHandle( hFile );
}
```

Comment: Your implementations do not work reliably. Your calculation of `biSizeImage` does not take scanline padding into account. For uncompressed RGB images this is best set to 0 anyway. Your calculation of `bfOffBits` fails to account for alignment requirements. Use `offsetof(BITMAPINFO, bmiColors[256])` instead. You are dumping genuinely random bytes, too (`empty`). There are more issues and it shows once again: Don't roll your own. Use the [Windows Imaging Component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee719902.aspx) - it's there for a reason.

Answer (score 1):

You need to force the output to be written in **binary** format, not text, this is chosen when you open your file/create your stream and to output all the values as bytes, not integers, this can be done in a number of ways possibly the easiest being write `chr(0)` or `chr(255)` - you also need to start your file with a header section - there are a number of formats that make this too long to go into in an answer here - some of them are down to preference as much as anything.  There is a good summary in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitmap_file_format#Bitmap_file_header).

Basically you have to inform the receiving applications which format you are using, the number of rows, columns and how the colours are stored.